# Jenkins job auto-versioning with maven-release-plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

is it possible to do the following.

I set up on jenkins maven-release-plugin. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin
He works. But I need to press Release and change the version manually.

How to do to make everything automatically after every commit? 
We've committed and jenkins automatically generate a new version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the maven-release-plugin approach, there is not much alternative to pressing the button and entering the release number.

What's simpler and works better for many purposes is to avoid that. Instead:

- manage the first two or three digits of the version number manually by simply editing the pom and committing/pushing changes.
- have the last digit come from a build number supplied by jenkins.

Tutorials on slightly different approaches to do this [here](http://akeffalas.github.io/blog/2014/04/jenkins-build-info-maven-artifacts.html) and [here](http://labs.bsb.com/2014/02/better-maven-releases-with-jenkins/).

Comment: Thanks for a comment. The fact that many just suspended over this plugin. Maybe there is some other plug-ins for jenkins to working with Maven-release-plugin. I can not just pick up and go the other way.

Comment: I found a very interesting tutorial. But it is not sure if he would make what I need.